# How can a script and setTimeout/setInterval work together in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading through the [NodeJS Event Loop description](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) I wonder how `setTimeout` and `setInterval` can actually work.

The page says NodeJS first runs the given script (let REPL alone for now) and **then** enters the event loop. But what if I call `setTimeout` in that script and expect it to trigger while the script is still running? Isn't that the normal case actually? According to the description the timer callback will not be triggered before the main script ends, which sounds really weird to me.

For those interested, here's the NodeJS outer even loop (there are actually 2 nested loops): https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.cc#L4526

Comment: What exactly do you understand by "while the script is still running"?

Comment: As described [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#event-loop-explained). NodeJS will process the initial script and then moves on to the event loop. What if the initial script never returns (e.g. has an own loop) but wants to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, if the script blocks - *hangs* - then the timeout callback will never get a chance to execute. That's exactly why we need to write *non-blocking* code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**let's do this by example**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    print('there');
});

print('hi');
```

this will print `hi` then `there`

here's what happen

the script will be proccessed until last line and when ever it finds a timer function
it will add it to a queue which will be handled later `at the end of the execution` by the queue scheduler

`loop queue => [ setTimeout ]`

before exit there should be a scheduler, some kind of a loop to check if we
have something in the queue and handle them, then once queue is out of all timers the loop
will exit.

let's suppose we call `setTimeout` inside `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        print('hi')
    }, 500);
}, 1000);
```

`loop queue => [ setInterval ]`

after `1000 ms`

setInterval will be fired and the inner `setTimeout` will be added to the queue

`loop queue => [ setTimeout, setInterval ]`

now we get back to the `main loop` which will wait for another `500` ms
an fire the inner setTimeout function, then remove it from the queue
because setTimeout should be run once.

`loop queue => [ setInterval ]`

back to the main loop, we still have items in the queue, so it will wait
another `500 ms` and fire again `( 500 + 500 = 1000 ms)`
the inner setTimeout function will be added to the queue again

`loop queue => [ setTimeout, setInterval ]`

back to the main queue agin and again ...

Now this is simply how timers work, they are not meant to handle blocking code, it's
a way to run code at some intervals

```
setInterval(function(){
    // do something long running here
    while (1) {}
    setTimeout(function(){
        print('hi')
    }, 500);
}, 1000);
```

main loop will block here and the inner timeout will not be added to the queue, so this
is a bad idea

nodejs and event loop in general are good with network operations because they don't block when
used with `select` for example.

```
setInterval(function(){
    // check if socket has something
    if (socketHasData( socket )){
        processSocketData( socket );
    }

    // do something else that does not block
    // maybe schedule another timer here
    print('hello');
}, 1000);
```

`libuv` which is the event loop used in nodejs, uses threads to handle some
blocking operations like IO operations, open/read/write files

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] humm re-reading your initial post, I think I know what bugs you. You mentioned `nodejs` in your post, implying you might be coding a server.

If you are not really familiar with server side JavaScript and more used to php server for example it might be very confusing indeed.

With a php server, a request creates a new thread that will handle it and when the *main script* (as you call it) ends, then the thread is killed and nothing else runs on the server (except for the webserver that listens to request, like `nginx` or `apache`).

With nodejs, it's different. The main thread is alone and **always running**. So when a request arrives, callbacks are fired but they are still in that single thread. Said otherwise: **the main script never ends** (except when you kill it or that your server crashes :) )

---

Well, that is accurate. Because of the **single-threaded** nature of JavaScript, if a **timer ends while the main thread is busy, the timer's callback will wait**.

When you do

```
setTimeout(callback, 1000)
```

You are not saying "I want this callback to be called in exactly 1s" but actually "I want this callback to be called in, at least, 1s"

This article by John Resig is an excellent read and goes through the details of the JavaScript's timers https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Unfortunately you made some wrong assumptions :-) I'm neither implementing a server nor am I used to PHP. What I'm after is to know how a timer callback set in the main script can every trigger in NodeJS given that it is single threaded? I studied the NodeJS source code for a while, but it's not at all obvious how this can work. To me it looks as if there is no callback triggered until the main script is finished.

Comment: Oups too bad :/ Well I think the confusion lies with what you call the **main script**. I am not sure I see what you are talking about.

Comment: Note: timers in browser are a different thing since there are several threads involved, which NodeJS however does not use, from what I see. Still, even in browsers this can only work if the JS engine supports inserting callbacks at arbitrary times or they will never run while a script runs.

Comment: BTW is the nodejs source code easy to read. I am not sure I am able to do that!!!

Comment: About the main script: see the linked description. It says NodeJS first loads the given script and runs it and **after** that ended it starts the event loop.

Comment: Ok so I guess this question is completely out of my current knowledge then :) You seem to know a lot more than I do

Comment: That said, it actually makes sense what the **main script** is. But then I am not sure what your question is. I think this article answers that question perfectly https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> But what if I call `setTimeout` in that script and expect it to trigger while the script is still running?

You don't expect that. You expect your synchronous code run to completion way before the timeout occurs.

If the script is still running, because it's doing something blocking - it *hangs* - then the timeout callback doesn't get a chance to execute, it will wait. That's exactly why we need to write non-blocking code.

> Isn't that the normal case actually?

No. Most of the time no JS is executing, the event loop is idling (while there might be background tasks doing the heavy lifting).

Comment: Imagine the case you run a script that tests something. It takes a while to run and wants to show progress. For that it uses a timer to coalesce progress ticks into a not-to-small interval. The progress output would never be shown until the test script ends, if you are right. What is `setTimeout` good for then?

Comment: Yes. If the test code is running synchronously, it also needs to write the progress output synchronously. (You still can use `Date` to figure out timing). When it wants to use `setTimeout`, is has to run the tests asynchronously, i.e. at least running each test in its own process tick.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Node is single threaded, it (v8 engine) always executes the current script before moving on to the next one. So when we start a node server with a main script, it loads, parses, compiles and executes that script first, before it runs anything else. Only if the current running script hits an I/O call it gets bumped out to the back of the event loop, giving other scripts or `setTimeout` callbacks a chance to execute. This is the very nature of JavaScript engine and the reason Node is not considered good for long running, in-memory CPU intensive tasks.

As @atomrc said in his answer, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are just a hint to node to run the callbacks **after** the timeout period, there are no guarantees.